# Why I got this error? I've not do anythink except trying work

Tags: javascript, dom

I got a new project which already finished and started using. I've just tried work on my local some pictures in the main page aren't shown. I checked inspector/console so I've got a error abaout js. This project is a php project and working with wamp server. I couldn't solve it because I'am not a frontend dev. İs there anybody can help me about this situation? Thanks everyone,

```
  function e() {
            var e = P[d].targetOrigin;
            h(d, "[" + a + "] Sending msg to iframe[" + d + "] (" + b + ") targetOrigin: " + e),
            c.contentWindow.postMessage(K + b, e)
        }
```

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
> provided ('https://www.jetsms.net') does not match the recipient
> window's origin ('http:`
>
> dragiframe.js:43 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
> "https://www.jetsms.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
> at addHandle (https://www.jetsms.net/chatadmin/assets/cmodule-chat/js/dragiframe.js:43:19)
> at onload (https://www.jetsms.net/chatadmin/index.php/visitors/chatbox/chatpanel/d1V3rb4CfQOqapFg6G9v?e=biotekno%40biotekno.com.tr&n=%231-meryema-BIOTEKNO%20&dn=MERYEM%20%20AYDIN:47:138)

Comment: You can't access a https context from a http context, for security reasons.